# Error when creating a Double linked List in a form

Tags: c#

I am new to C#, and I am trying to create a step by step program that will create and display the nodes of a double linked list. I will show what I have so far:

This is the code for the form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Pruebapila2
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DbLinList infoTask;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            infoTask = new DbLinList();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            taskToDo vInfo = new taskToDo(int.Parse(textBox1.Text), textBox4.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox5.Text, textBox3.Text);
            infoTask.insertAtTheEnd(vInfo);
            listBox1.Items.Add("Data Added: "+ vInfo.id + " - " + vInfo.name + " - " + vInfo.length + " - " + vInfo.percentage + " - " + vInfo.programmer);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            Node n;

            n = infoTask.firstNode;
            while (n != null)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(n.info.id) + "\t" + n.info.name + "\t" + n.info.length);
                n = n.Next;
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            Node n;

            n = infoTask.firstNode;
            while (n != null)
            {
                if (n.info.id == int.Parse(textBox6.Text))
                listBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(n.info.id) + "\t" + n.info.name + "\t" + n.info.length);
                n = n.Next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you click on the first button of the form, it will insert the data into a Node, the node belongs to a double linked list, therefore here is the code for the list.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Pruebapila2
{
    class DbLinList
    {
        public Node firstNode;

        public DbLinList()
        {
            firstNode = null;
        }

        public DbLinList insertAtTheEnd(taskToDo vTaskToDo)
        {
            Node newNode;
            newNode = new Node(vTaskToDo);
            newNode.Next = firstNode;
            newNode.Prev = firstNode.Next;
            firstNode = newNode;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

This list uses a Node that has a link to the previous node, and a link to the next node of the list. Here is the code for the Node:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Pruebapila2
{
    class Node
    {
        public taskToDo info;
        public Node Next;
        public Node Prev;

        public Node(taskToDo vInfo)
        {
            info = vInfo;
            Next = null;
            Prev = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The node is reusable because it can contain any type of info, and even several parts of information, but in this case this node will contain information about a task that a programmer has to make, for that reason I created a tasks.cs file, which will contain the information that we need to store on the list. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Pruebapila2
{
    class taskToDo
    {
            public int id;
            public string name;
            public string length;
            public string percentage;
            public string programmer;

            public taskToDo(int vID, String vName, String vLength, String vPercentage, String vProgrammer)
            {
                id = vID;
                name = vName;
                length = vLength;
                percentage = vPercentage;
                programmer = vProgrammer;
        }

    }
}
```

The code shows no errors and no warnings, when executed, it displays the ERROR: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in DoubleLinkedTest.exe." But I have no clue as to why is this error appearing.

The logic here is the following: The button sends the data to the list, the list creates a new node, the node creates a new task, and the info is stored in the node.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code, why is not working?. The functions of the button number 2 and 3 are not in question at the moment.

This is how the form looks like:[image: Form Example]

Thank you very much for your Help on this!.

Comment: You're using `firstNode` without ever setting it to anything but `null` - hence the `NullReferenceException`. If you'd just use a debugger, you'd see it at a glance. In short - your code is very wrong, and you need to rethink what you're doing.

Comment: The constructor starts the `firstNode` as `null`, but when the function is called, the firstNode is no longer `null`

Comment: Just saying your code is very wrong does not really helps on where to go to fix it...

Comment: Learn to use a debugger - this is a trivial problem you'll see in half a second in a debugger. Seriously. `firstNode.Next` is accessed before you ever assign `firstNode` in `insertAtTheEnd`.

Comment: Any further insight on the "learn to use a debugger"?. This is a vague answer, and does not point to the direction on how to fix the code.

Comment: I told you the exact line of code where the exception is thrown and why. What else do you want?

Comment: Good steps would be, to say where to see this on the debugger, and also which debugger?. And why `firstNode.Next` is accesed before it is assigned. Lastly, how to fix the code to make it work, which is the answer requested, not where to look on the debugger...

Comment: Ah, you want someone to fix your code for you and teach you how to use tools. StackOverflow isn't really the best place for that - you might want to try some programming forum for that. StackOverflow isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: I am not asking for a code example, neither someone who teaches how to code, as the question itself says, I think I've made most of the code to work, however is not working yet, and I fail to understand why.